# How do I withdraw my bitcoins and spend them?

Tags: exchanges, sell-bitcoins

I run a small business online.  I am interested in using Bitcoin to accept monies from my customers but to be honest the whole thing has me a bit confused.  I am in the UK how would I be able to exchange my Bitcoins for £ sterling and then subsequently spend it?

Answer (score 6):

Trade them for USD, GBP or EUR on a trading site such as https://mtgox.com and transfer it to your bank account.

Or you can spend them directly at any other business that accepts bitcoins as payment.

Answer (score 5):

If you use a payment processor such as [BitPay](http://bitpay.com) or [WalletBit](http://walletbit.com), they will take care of the conversion to fiat for you (for a fee, of course).

You could also use e-commerce software and manage the exchange to fiat yourself.  That's what [CoinDL](http://coindl.com), for instance, does using a Bitcoin module for OpenCart [e-commerce software](http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category%3aShopping_Cart_Interfaces).

There might also be a number of [goods and services](http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade) you would use where bitcoins are accepted for payment.